# Open web.config.comments file (default web.config)

Tags: .net, web-config, comments

I am trying to check some settings in the general web.config.comments file, located in the
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG-folder. I get an error message:

> Windows can´t open this file. To open this file, ... etc.

It is the standard windows message when opening of a file fails, you have probably seen it.
I use Windows 7 and the windows shell.

How do I open this file?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? You didn't describe the issue.

Comment: Opening the file... ;) perhaps not an issue for this page?!

Comment: What is the problem with opening the file?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: What platform? What are you using to open it? How are you accessing the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can open it with notepad ;) Thanks for your effors

Comment: So the issue was that there is no default file association for `.comments` files?

Comment: So, this is not a programming question. and off-topic.

Comment: I thought so. Move it? Delete it?

Comment: I voted to move it to superuser. You can flag it for moderator attention and ask them to move it there.